# How is Amazon Ec2 running usage counted if I'm hosting a website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm set a website using the Amazon free tier in an EC2 instance. The free tier is giving me 750 hours of EC2 Linux t2.micro instance usage. I would like to know how the instance hours are counted to ensure the usage doesn't exceed the free tier limit.

I suppose if my website is not down the instance should be running 24 hours a day which will result in a maximum of 24 hours x 31 days = 744 hours per month usage.

Is that the case?

Comment: *"24 hours x 31 days = 744 hours per week"*  ...per week?

Comment: Modified to per month, was a mistype, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) provides 750 hours per month for a t2.micro Linux instance.

Therefore, if you keep **one t2.micro Linux instance running for an entire month**, then there is no charge for Amazon EC2.

You could, alternatively, run **two instances for half a month each**, since that would combine to the same total hours.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 instance usage is calculated by the second or by the hour, depending on which AMI you're using:

- per-second for most Linux distributions
- per-hour for Windows, and for Linux distributions that have a separate hourly charge

If your instance is per-second, then you're billed a minimum of 60 seconds each time an instance starts.

If your instance is per-hour, then you're billed a minimum of one hour each time an instance starts.

An instance is considered to be 'started' when it enters the running [state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html).